# Extra rows in WPF Data Template

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

## Extra rows in WPF DataTemplate Specification

This seems to be a really good overview of WPF Data Binding from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview

The page has links to a PDF download (which seems more comprehensive than the page itself): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/opbuildpdf/framework/wpf/data/toc.pdf?branch=live and a sample application: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=163703.

### Question:

In the sample application file: `DataBindingLabApp.xaml` *(~ line 50)* a data template is defined for individual list items. The template specifies 4 rows but only two rows are used...  Is there a good reason for having unused rows?

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:AuctionItem}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray"
                Padding="7" Name="border" Margin="3" Width="500">
            <Grid>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>   <!-- not needed? -->
                    <RowDefinition/>   <!-- not needed? -->
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    ...
```

I deleted 2 of the rows and as far as I can tell (by comparing screen shots) the extra rows make no difference to the appearance of the list items. Is there any reason they should be retained? The only thing I can think of is for some future functionality *(but that seems like a poor practice, no?)*

Comment: So many nuances, it's hard to know what's what sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason they should be retained?

Unless there are any items in the `Grid` that sets the `Grid.Row` attached property to either `2` or `3` you could remove them unless you want the top two (the only two) rows to fill only 50% of the `Grid`'s total height.

A `RowDefinition` has a default height of `Auto` which means that the available space will be divided equally among the number of `<RowDefinition/>` elements that you define.

> ...as far as I can tell (by comparing screen shots) the extra rows make no difference to the appearance of the list items. Is there any reason they should be retained?

No.

> The only thing I can think of is for some future functionality (but that seems like a poor practice, no?)

Yes, then you might as well add them later.

Comment: Hmm, thank you.  I'll have to study the code a bit more - I'm not seeing a 50% height reduction with the row definitions deleted...

Comment: Well, I guess you could delete the superfluous RowDefinitions then.

Comment: Yes, I guess I realized that already. I'm trying to learn WPF and C# coming from VBA and I'm not in Kansas anymore... so this is somewhat of a learning opportunity; trying to understand what changes layout and why... _(on an already steep learning curve)_.